# How do you make Docker Swarm in Docker for Windows (WSL2) joinable by another device on the LAN?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I run Docker Swarm from my desktop PC running **Docker Desktop** for Windows in WSL2 mode.  I tried to fiddle with the firewall settings but it does not appear to allow my Raspberry Pi 4 connected over the LAN on WiFi running Docker to connect to it.

I can access the ports that are exposed in `ports` with no issue from other devices over the network, but the Docker swarm ports are not set up in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

How is the Raspberry Pi 4 connected ? USB, Wifi or lan ?  If you're building an iot app connecting to a server service running in your docker image, try running the server service directly in the workstation (not in a docker).